# Insert text from an excel file into a word document (Word VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Since my documents usually have certain phrases that can be used over and over again, I want to hotkey them all to save time. To be more specific, I plan to make, let say, Macro1 (insert "Of course"), Macro2 (insert "The issue is"), and Macro3 (insert "by the time"), hotkeyed to Alt +1,2,3 respectively. If I press Alt + 2, "The issue is" got inserted instantly at my cusor.

Here's the base macro I'm using:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Selection.TypeText Text:="sample text"
End Sub
```

The problem is for any new document, the content of Macro1, 2, and 3 will often need to be changed. I plan on creating an excel file to house all the phrases for ease of edit, but don't know how to link its specific cells back to the word macros. Is there a way to do that?

Note: I'm aware of the AutoText or Building Block function in word, but I don't find them as easy to edit as an excel table.

Comment: Have you tried `mail merge`?

Comment: Not yet very clear. Do you want to fill existing fields in word (as in mailmerge), or something like creating hotkeys to insert phrases while typing manually?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible to get the contents of an Excel cell into a Word document.  In fact there are probably dozens of ways, which each are used in different situations.  Can you give some examples of before & after?  Why would there be **several** macros?  More information please.

Comment: I updated the question. Hope my intention is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, assuming yor Excel file is located in "C:\temp\" and yor phrases are saved in first Worksheet and First column:
This Function will read the first cell (A1) from this excel file:

```
Function Read_Excel_Cell(cellRin As Long) As String

    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim myWB As Excel.Workbook

    Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
    Set myWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\phrases.xlsx")
    Read_Excel_Cell = myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(cellRin, 1)
    myWB.Close
    Set myWB = Nothing
    Set oExcel = Nothing

End Function
```

And this Macro will insert it into document:

```
Sub InsertText1()
    Selection.TypeText Text:=Read_Excel_Cell(1)
End Sub
```

So you can create in this way as many macros as you need and using the same function Read_Excel_Cell() you can refere to another row.

To make this running in the Word vba you must add Excel Reference (in Tools\References tick Microsoft Excel Object Library).